# how to read XmlDocument by maximumn attribute to minimum attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, system.xml

I am reading XmlDocument in dotnet/c#, by using System.Xml, i like to read xmlElement by More attributes to less attribute, how to read? can we do this?

my example xml file and coding:

```
<conditions><condition if:size="10pt" if:name="courier"/>
<condition if:size="10pt"/>
<condition if:size="10pt" if:name="times" ifnot:emphasis="bold"/></conditions>

            foreach (XmlElement CondNode in XmlDoc.SelectNodes("//condition"))
{
//how to read and sort(not by length) by no. of attribute

}
```

i expect to read below order:

```
<condition if:size="10pt" if:name="times" ifnot:emphasis="bold"/>
<condition if:size="10pt" if:name="courier"/>
<condition if:size="10pt"/>
```

Thanks in advance,

Saran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using XmlDocument, you can sort your nodes like this:

```
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//condition")
               .OfType<XmlElement>()
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Attributes.Count);
foreach (XmlElement CondNode in nodes)
{
     //how to read and sort(not by length) by no. of attribute
}
```

By using [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you retrieve all XmlElements from the collection (this should comprise all nodes in your collection) and receive an `IEnumerable<XmlElement>` as the result. You can use this as the starting point for Linq queries. [XmlNodeList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) only implements the non-generic version of `IEnumerable` so that you can't run Linq queries on it as most of the methods are extension methods for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Hi Markus, Thanks you very much for great help and exact what i expect

Comment: Hi Markus, I have one more doubt, Can i count namespace attribute only, for sorting? thanks

Comment: @saravanans: if you want to only use a specific namespace prefix when sorting, you could try the following: `.OrderByDescending(x => x.Attributes.OfType<XmlAttribute>().Where(a => a.Prefix == "if").Count());`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time for me! it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

using Linq to XML

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var sorted = doc.Descendants("condition").OrderByDescending(node => node.Attributes().Count());
foreach (XElement condition in sorted)
{
    // Do whatever you need
}
```

Comment: Hi pjotr, Thanks you very much for great help and exact what i expect